# assign linq result to an object variable and then get value from that object Variable

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a situation that needs to assign a `LINQ result` to a `Button.Tag` property.
and when that button clicks, iterate throughout that `LINQ result` placed in the `Button.Tag`
**HINT :** LINQ result is type of `List<anonymousType>`. for some reason, i don't what to return `List<KnownType>`
any idea?
**EDIT :**  As you all suggested, i reconsider problem and decided to create a specific class type and put `DataTableRowId` in the class instead of whole `DataTableRow` thing.
therefore anonymous Type Like `new {Class1=c1, Class2=c2, DataTableRow3=dr3}` changed to
class of type:

```
public class CustomClass
{
    public Class1 c1 { get; set; }
    public Class c2 { get; set; }
    public int DataTableRow3Id dr3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "for some reason"? That's clearly information you have which you could explain to us...

Comment: so dynamic doesn't work with you?

Comment: @Jon Skeet created `anonymousType` is combination of some common classes and a **row of specific DataTable**

Comment: @Rzassar: So why does that mean you don't want to create a type for the result? Basically you've given no justification for why you have to use an anonymous type here.

Comment: @JonSkeet isn't this a reasonable use of dynamic, when you don't want to make a class based on properties that are of internal .Net Framework UI types, like ListViewItem?

Comment: @MEYWD: I don't see how therre are internal .NET Framework UI types involved here, nor do I see any need for using `dynamic`. The OP *could* use `dynamic`, but I suspect that creating a specific type to encapsulate the results woulld be cleaner.

Comment: @JonSkeet what i meant by internal are classes that are of a specific purpose, not like string for example, well you are right about it being cleaner to make a specific type, although i would convert the data to my own type before using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access anonymous types this way, You can make a custom class and create the result of linq to that custom type. Assign this object to tag and later type cast it back to your custom type.